# Favorites left join

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a site where you can see venues. When you click on a single venue it displays a popup with it. There is a favorite button which can be active or not. This code is in ajax for this popup

```
SELECT * FROM venue_datetime
LEFT JOIN venue_calendar ON venue_datetime.calendar = venue_calendar.calendar_id
LEFT JOIN venue_events ON venue_calendar.event = venue_events.event_id
LEFT JOIN venue ON venue_events.venue = venue.venue_id
LEFT JOIN favorites ON venue.venue_id = favorites.favorites_venue_id OR venue.venue_id is null
LEFT JOIN users ON favorites.favorites_user_id = users.id OR favorites.favorites_user_id is null
WHERE datetime_id = ? AND id = ?
```

This part is not working as it was intended.

```
LEFT JOIN favorites ON venue.venue_id = favorites.favorites_venue_id OR venue.venue_id is null
LEFT JOIN users ON favorites.favorites_user_id = users.id OR favorites.favorites_user_id is null
```

Any ideas?

Comment: No ideas.  I, for one, have no idea what is intended.  It is a good idea to include sample data and desired results.  These usually convey more information than code that doesn't work.

Comment: Load your sample data to sqlfiddle .. mentioned what is the current output and what is expected

Comment: Not sure why you need the OR.  Left joins include all records from the left table and only those that match on the right.  So it's irrelevant to say `venue.venue_ID is null` or `favorites.favorites_user_Id is null` as the left join automatically include them.  The or's would be needed if this was included as a where clause or it would negate the left joins.  Perhaps the problem is with datetime_Id and id.  what tables are these from? perhaps it's those that need the `or fieldname is null`.  Do you get all the desired results and more if you exclude the where clause?

Comment: Why do you have `OR venue.venue_id is null` on the end of the left join ON clause for the favorites table? That would appear to mean that if there is no venue then every favourite will be counted (same for using `OR favorites.favorites_user_id is null` on the LEFT JOIN for the users table.

Comment: datetime_id is from venue_datetime
id is from users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments

```
SELECT * FROM venue_datetime
LEFT JOIN venue_calendar ON venue_datetime.calendar = venue_calendar.calendar_id
LEFT JOIN venue_events ON venue_calendar.event = venue_events.event_id
LEFT JOIN venue ON venue_events.venue = venue.venue_id
LEFT JOIN favorites ON venue.venue_id = favorites.favorites_venue_id 
LEFT JOIN users ON favorites.favorites_user_id = users.id 
WHERE datetime_id = ? AND (users.id = ? or users.id is null)
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM venue_datetime
LEFT JOIN venue_calendar ON venue_datetime.calendar = venue_calendar.calendar_id
LEFT JOIN venue_events ON venue_calendar.event = venue_events.event_id
LEFT JOIN venue ON venue_events.venue = venue.venue_id
LEFT JOIN favorites ON venue.venue_id = favorites.favorites_venue_id 
LEFT JOIN users ON favorites.favorites_user_id = users.id 
  AND users.id = ?
WHERE datetime_id = ?
```

When using outer joins criteria has to take into account null values. So either the joins must handle is null from tables not returning all values OR you must put the limiting criteria on the join itself.

Comment: The idea is if there are no records in favorites for that user exclude these two lines

LEFT JOIN favorites ON venue.venue_id = favorites.favorites_venue_id 
LEFT JOIN users ON favorites.favorites_user_id = users.id

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.  Your join is presently setup so that if there are records in venue include all of them (provided there is a venu event and a venu calendar and a venu date time) and ONLY those in favorites which match.  If you're wanting all records in users or favorites, you should be using a right join, and then I'd have to revisit the where clause.  Some sample data with current results and expected results would help.

Comment: [link](http://screencast.com/t/hCqE5mcOhaK) Here is data model. Venue data should be returned in any case, but favorites only if they exist.
Anyway only one record should be returned. And favorite could be 1 or 0

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the user will always be there, then maybe do this:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM venue_datetime
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = ?
LEFT JOIN venue_calendar ON venue_datetime.calendar = venue_calendar.calendar_id
LEFT JOIN venue_events ON venue_calendar.event = venue_events.event_id
LEFT JOIN venue ON venue_events.venue = venue.venue_id
LEFT JOIN favorites ON venue.venue_id = favorites.favorites_venue_id AND favorites.favorites_user_id = users.id 
WHERE datetime_id = ?
```

Join the users to the venue just on the users id, then left join the favourites based on both the venue and user.